# How to minitest show action rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, ruby-on-rails-6

How to association test the show, edit, update, and destroy action in mini-test cases?

**Post.rb**

```
Class Post < ApplicationRecord
   
   belongs_to :topic
end
```

**Topic.rb**

```
Class Topic < ApplicationRecord
   
   has_many :posts
end
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_topic
   
   def show
      @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
   end

   private 

   def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   end
end
```

**test/fixtures/topics.yml**

```
one: 
  name: first_name
```

**test/fixtures/posts.yml**

```
one: 
  name: post_name
  topic: one
```

**test/controllers/posts_controller_test_path.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
    @topic = @post.topic
  end

  test "should show post" do
    get topic_post_path(@topic, @post)
    assert_response :success
    assert_template 'show'
  end  
end
```

I excepted that test case should be a pass but I got `Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=1017070366 [WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = $1 AND]`

How to solve this problem.

**Using Rails 6.0**